# Interpolating Stylus for loop values into selector

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, interpolation, stylus

I'm trying to do something that I think is probably simple -- output all h1 through h6 selectors. I had more success creating a mixin that also outputs a property and a value for that property than just interpolating into the selector, but even then I couldn't manage to create a mixin that would successfully take any arguments for the property and the value.

I **might** have ended up with a mixin that did the job in one particular place. How can I modify this solution so that I can use it for any property and value combination?

```
hcolor() {
    headings = 1 2 3 4 5 6
    selectorh = 'h'
    for hnumber, hnumber in headings {
        // join(selectorh, hnumber)
        +cache('h' + hnumber) {
            color: colordarkgray
        }
        hnumber = hnumber +1
    }
}
```

One thing I've tried that didn't work:

```
hify(property, value) {
    headings = 1 2 3 4 5 6
    selectorh = 'h'
    for hnumber, hnumber in headings {
        // join(selectorh, hnumber)
        +cache('h' + hnumber) {
            {property}: {value}
        }
        hnumber = hnumber +1
    }
}
```

Another attempt, informed by a [Sass](https://trulycode.com/bytes/sass-function-loop-headings-h1h2h3h4h5h6/) solution, throws no errors, but I don't know how to use it in a selector, if it works at all:

```
hify() {
    hstart = 1
    hstop = 6
    headings = 1 2 3 4 5 6
    for hnumber in headings {
        if hnumber < hstop {
            return 'h{hnumber}, '
        }
        else if hnumber == hstop {
            return 'h{humber}'
        }
        hnumber = humber + 1
    }
}
```

I feel like I must be close, but I can't adapt the information about Stylus [interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html) and [default functions](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html) into a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a slightly modified version of your Sass example:

```
headings($from = 1, $to = 6)
  if $from == $to
    'h' + $from
  else
    'h' + $from + ',' + headings($from + 1, $to)

{headings(1, 4)}
  color: red
  background: blue
```

Comment: Excellent. I guess the tricky thing is how line 5 from your solution works instead of a traditional for loop.